# Java config file multidimensional array

Tags: java, classloader

I have a problem. For my code I have a config file with the following content:

```
updateOnInsert=true
removeLast=false

names=Joey Greek, Lisa Blessing, Arnold Verdict
```

To read this config file, I have the following code:

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("configs/main.config");
                
// Read all properties from agent strategy file
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(is);

// Assign all properties to variables
boolean updateOnInsert = Boolean.parseBoolean(properties.getProperty("updateOnInsert"));
boolean removeLast = Boolean.parseBoolean(properties.getProperty("removeLast"));

List<String> names = Arrays.asList(properties.getProperty("names").split(", ", -1));
```

But now I need to change the format of the names to:

```
names=[[Joey, Greek], [Lisa, Blessing], [Arnold, Verdict]]
```

The output varialbe has to be of the type: `String[][]` with as result:

```
[0] => [Joey, Greek]
[1] => [Lisa, Blessing]
[2] => [Arnold, Verdict]
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Is it Spring application?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Are you just asking for an opinion on what is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what the input could look like. The safest way would probably be to use a proper parser (and maybe a different file format).

If the list is always in the form `[[Name], [Name]]` and `Name` never contains brackets, a simple way could be to use a more specialized regex, e.g. `(?<=\]),\s*(?=\[)`.

Rundown on the regex:

- `(?<=\])`: a positive look-behind, i.e. any match must follow a `]`.
- `,\s*`: the actual match to split at (and remove), i.e. a comma followed by any whitespace
- `(?=\[)")`: a positive look-ahead, i.e. any match must be followed by a `[`.

Finally, split each of the names by `,` to get the 2D array:

```
//results in Strings like "[Joey, Greek]", "[Lisa, Blessing]", and "[Arnold, Verdict]"
String[] completeNames = properties.getProperty("names").split("(?<=\\]),\\s*(?=\\[)");

//We're using a stream here but you could as well use traditional loops   
String[][] namesInParts = Arrays.stream(completeNames)
           //map the name by removing the brackets and splitting at the comma (followed by any whitespace)
           .map(name -> name.replaceAll("[\\]\\[]", "").split(",\\s*"))
           //collect everything into a new array
           .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
String[][] names = Pattern.compile(", ", -1)
                          .splitAsStream(properties.getProperty("names"))
                          .map(s -> s.split(" "))
                          .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Given a list of names, first stream the names list.
- then split the names on one or more spaces.
- and put the resulting array in a "two-D" array

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList(properties.getProperty("names").split(", ", -1));
String[][] result = names.stream().map(str->str.split("\\s+")).toArray(String[][]::new);
```

You can make this a single statement by streaming the original list as it is read from the properties file.  I omitted that to simplify the explanation.